# Два массива и объекты внутри них

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два массива

```
let store = {
   users: [
     {name: 'Tol', age: 13},
     {name: 'Tol2', age: 15},
  ]
}

let newData = {
   users: [
     {name: 'Tol', age: 13},
     {name: 'Tol3', age: 15},
     {name: 'Tol4', age: 15},
   ]
}
```

Есть функция, которая добавляет **users** из массива **newData** в массив **users** объекта **Store**

```
function addUser (newData.users) {
   store.users = store.users.concat(newData.users);
}
```

Но мне надо в этой функции еще проверять, а не существует ли уже в массиве **store.users** такого юзера и если не существует, то только тогда проводить concat(), иначе пропускать добавление.

Comment: Самый чистый JS )

Comment: У тебя это не массивы, а объекты уже (хотя все мы знаем что массивы это объекты тоже), вот разница: Объект = `{key: value}` Массив = `[_index: value]`, индекс *спрятан* и это тоже ключ, но `0-n`

Comment: поправил код, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let store = {
   users: [
     {name: 'Tol', age: 13},
     {name: 'Tol2', age: 15},
  ]
}

let newData = {
   users: [
     {name: 'Tol', age: 13},
     {name: 'Tol3', age: 15},
     {name: 'Tol4', age: 15},
   ]
}

function addUser(newUsers) {
   store.users = store.users.concat(
     newUsers.filter(nu => !store.users.find(su => su.name == nu.name))
   );
}

addUser(newData.users);

console.log(store.users.length, store.users);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addUser( newData ){
    newData.users.forEach( newUser => {
        let has = store.users.some( user => user.name === newUser.name );
        if( !has ) store.users.push( newUser );
    });
}
```